# Generating number between these start and end fields

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 column (ID, Start and End) in TSQL.

```
ID; Start; END
1; 1; 5;
2; 10; 15;
```

So it will generate number like:

```
1, 1
1, 2
1, 3
1, 4
1, 5
2, 10
2, 11
2, 12
2, 13
2, 14
2, 15
```

Again all I can think of is cursor but is there any better way?

Comment: Sounds like something better done in _application code_, not SQL.

Comment: @Oded: Unfortunetly this needs to be done in TSQL due to it's SSIS package. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CTE approach is easy

```
with tab as(
select 1 as id, 1 as start, 5 as en
union all
select 2, 10, 15),
 cte as(
select id,start,en from tab
union all
select id,start+1 , en from cte where start+1<=en)
select id,start from cte
order by id
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I like this approach cause it doesn't require me to create sequential number which is good. It's fast as well.

Comment: @josepj1989: I got an issue which basically the recursive more than 100 numbers. I can solve this by appending OPTION (MACRECURSION 1000) but not sure where to put this.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this (untested)

```
;WITH cNumbers AS
(
   SELECT
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c1.object_id) AS ArbitraryNumber
   FROM
       sys.columns c1 CROSS JOIN sys.columns c2
)
SELECT
    M.ID, N.ArbritraryNumber
FROM
    MyTable M
    JOIN
    cNumbers N ON N.ArbitraryNumber BETWEEN M.Start AND M.End
```

Edit:

The cross join gives 298,116 rows in my tempdb. And 1,865,956 in a user DB. 
If nearly 300k isn't enough, add another CROSS JOIN.

This gives me 162,771,336 in tempdb and 2,548,895,896 in a user DB:

```
SELECT
    COUNT_BIG(*) --note bigint
FROM
    sys.columns c1 CROSS JOIN sys.columns c2 CROSS JOIN sys.columns c3
```

Comment: How are we sure that Arbitrary Number will cover all the range which might be required?

Comment: Ah the CTE stuff ... I didn't though about that. I will explore this

Comment: @gbn: the number that I got is phone number range which is 0296620382 - 096620399. So the number it never get 10 digits. So is it necessary to go through this c1.ObjectID stuff ?

Comment: @dewacorp.alliances: If I understand correctly, add another CROSS JOIN to give more numbers. c1.ObjectID is random. I use sys.columns because it always has at least 500 rows or so

Comment: @gbn: I did try that and it takes while in the query to generate a range between 0296620382 - 096620399.  Is there any other approach?